# Capture Windows packets at library level

Tags: tls

I am currently trying to debug and figure out of how the network aspect of an application work, however the traffic is encrypted, and only TLS packets are available via wireshark. I have heard that there are some programs (like [oSpy](https://github.com/oleavr/ospy), but this one works for 32 bits programs only) that are capable of directly hook to the encrypt/decrypt functions of Windows' dll and read traffic this way. If anyone knew a clean, new version of such "SSL dll hook", I'd be glad to hear about it.

PS: I can't use a proxy too, because my app obviously won't accept the proxy's certificate. I don't have access to the server's master key either ofc, and reading the client's master key would be a huge mess I don't want to get into.

Comment: "because my app obviously won't accept the proxy's certificate" - can't you just generate a CA certificate and install it on your box? This is how I MitM most TLS stuff with Burp and CANAPE.

Comment: I don't think this would work, the app looks for a specific server's certificate. I've been trying to do it using fiddler's proxy, and installing its generated CA, but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: You'll probably need to patch out the pinning code in the application then.